# Eclipse axis2 plugin: "Error parsing WSDL"

Tags: eclipse, soap, ant, wsdl, apache-axis

I'm trying to generate Java code from a WSDL. When trying to run the axis2 codegen ant target over a WSDL in my Eclipse project, I get:

`BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\...project\ant\build.xml:40: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: Error parsing WSDL`

Is there any means to have a stacktrace or a message of the exception or any logs with more information?

Answer (score 0):

When you call your ant script try -debug or -verbose that should give you more information